# How do I find log likelihood function based on observations

Tags: maximum-likelihood, likelihood, logarithm

Assuming the regression model Yi = BiXi + E is appropriate.

And I have observations : X1...X10, Y1...Y10

How do i find the log likelihood function based on the observed values?

Any help is much appreciated!

Edit: I forgot to add a few assumptions:

The error terms are normally distributed and independent with variance = 16

And that I am trying to find the log likelihood function of B1

Comment: Without assumptions the question is ill-posed. What are the assumptions?

Comment: What are some assumptions that are needed?

Comment: In particular, what likelihood function do you assume?

Comment: I'm only given that it is assumed that the regression model is Yi = BiXi + E

and i am trying to find the log likelihood function of Bi

Comment: Plus the errors being $iid$ $N(0,16)$, right?

Comment: That is correct!

Comment: Now that you have specified the probability distribution for each observation, it only remains to apply the definition of the likelihood and exploit the independence assumption.

Comment: So i use B1 = (Yi + E)/Xi?

The multiply the values together and log it?